# Вопрос про отправку формы

Tags: php, html, mysql

А вот вопрос: а если формам не присваивать имя и id, и несколько форм будут содержать одинаковые имена полей(input), не будет ли потом загвоздки при отправке запроса?

Comment: смотря для чего это сделано..

Comment: Редактирование товара сразу в прайс-листе при выгрузке, не хотел лишний раз id захломлять

Comment: идентификация в любом случае необходима, а как вы ее сделаете, вам решать.